# why contextloader is trying to load WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml if using mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets

in gradle web project, i want to load only mvc-dispatcher-servlet only but when i am starting tomcat by deploying below exception in tomcat console:

[image]

web.xml :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener> -->
```

> You can see i have commented contextLoaderListener still loading
>   applicationContext.xml.

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="<package-name>" />

 <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Please some1 help me out. I followed document and stackoverflow as well but didn't find solutions.

Thanks in advance for trying to help me!

> Note: I am using spring v.4.2.4 and i tried with 4.3.10 as well but
>   didn't work.

Comment: Do you only have a `web.xml` or also a `WebApplicationInitializer` and did you edit the correct `web.xml` the one in the sources not the generated/target one?

Comment: i have xml like packscontext.xml, redis.xml, syncfile.xml web.xml which i am importing in mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml which i didnot show in above mentioned code.